Store Named Attribute not working
I have two meshes. One is the generation of the node, the second is the application of this node.      But after applying all the Uv and normals disappeared and I want to return them and apply them.
But when I enabled Store Named Attribute again it stopped working




What should I do to apply the material correctly?
Different Store Named Attribute settings in generations




On the screenshot there's 2 named attributes, which one do you mean? Are you sure you want to set normal to $<0, 0, 0>$?

@MarkusvonBroady On the mesh on the left the same thing is used but without applying the geometry node. The original node is not mine and I'm still figuring out how it works. And only the Store Named Attribute changes the UV and Normals of the object making it pleasing to the eye
